# How to open dropdown on hover with angular instead of jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, angular

I would like to replace the following jquery statement in my client side with angular (7.x):

```
   //dropdown on hover in jquery

if($('.navbar').width() > 1007)
  {
    $('.nav .dropdown').hover(function() {
      $(this).addClass('open');
    },
    function() {
      $(this).removeClass('open');
    });
  }
```

By now I provisionally used ElementRef and Renderer2 together with corresponding (mouse...)-Eventlisteners. I could move this logic also to a directive with a Hostlistener...

```
   //element-wise angular code
<li #drop class="dropdown singleDro" (mouseover)="openDropDown($event)" (mouseleave)="closeDropDown($event)">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"
               class="dropdown-toggle"
               data-toggle="dropdown"
               role="button"
               aria-haspopup="true"
               aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fa fa-list-ul icon-dash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Listings <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a [routerLink]="['/dashboard/shop/add']">Add Shop</a></li>
              <li><a [routerLink]="['/dashboard/shop/view']">My Shops</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>


//component code
  openDropDown(event: Event) {
    if (this.navbarDash.nativeElement.offsetWidth > 1007) {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.drop.nativeElement, 'open');
    }
  }
  closeDropDown(event: Event) {
    this.renderer.removeClass(this.drop.nativeElement, 'open');
  }
```

...but I am looking for a more holistic solution, which has a similar effect like the jquery solution. I would prefer some solution on app-level which can be propagated to all children...

**Could you please give me hint which concept could help to achieve the described.**

Thank you

Hucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this worked:

```
import {Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropOpen]'
})
export class DropOpenDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  @HostListener('mouseover') onMouseOver() {
      const elementCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar');
    if (elementCollection[0].clientWidth > 1007) {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'open');
    }
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'open');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `NgClass`, when `mouseover` is triggered, you can just put a boolean to true.

Something like this:

```html
<li #drop 
class="dropdown singleDro" 
(mouseover)="isOpened = true" 
(mouseleave)="isOpened = false" 
ngClass="isOpened ? 'open' : ''">...dropdown-stuff..</li>
```

Comment: Thank you both for the hints which obviously work and are shorthands of my solution..the jquery code however has effect on all the dom. This code just effects one tag and I have to insert it manually in all dropdowns...What can be done to effect all dropdowns in on app-level and its children?

Comment: The smartest solution is to create a component that does this. Or you can abstract your class but you must check in every dropdown.

Comment: A component or a directive? How would be the concept of this component?

Comment: You can create directive, but i don't know how your logic is difficult in that dropdown. So you can choose the best approach

Comment: I think the `directive` is the best solution in this case. It is a bad thing to strongly match a logic of this type for a navigation bar. Angular is known to avoid such a pairing up in that way

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngClass` or `class.open` as follows

```html
<li #drop class="dropdown singleDro" 
[class.open]="isDropdownOpen"
(mouseover)="openDropDown($event)" 
(mouseleave)="closeDropDown($event)">...dropdown-stuff..</li>
```

or

```html
<li #drop class="dropdown singleDro" 
[ngClass]="{ 'open': isDropdownOpen}"
(mouseover)="openDropDown($event)" 
(mouseleave)="closeDropDown($event)">...dropdown-stuff..</li>
```

Within your component, define a class member called `isDropdownOpen` and simply toggle the value of it on hover

```js
  isDropdownOpen = false;

  ...

  openDropDown(event: Event) {
    if (this.navbarDash.nativeElement.offsetWidth > 1007) {
      this.isDropdownOpen = true;
    }
  }
  closeDropDown(event: Event) {
    this.isDropdownOpen = false;
  }
```